# Incorrect sorting in TableSorter

Tags: tablesorter

Strange behavoir in tablesorter:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var timeInSec = function(node) { return $(node).attr("time") };
    var sortDigit = { sorter : "digit" };

    $("#agentRapport").tablesorter({ 
        headers: {
            1: sortDigit,
            2: sortDigit
        },
        textExtraction: {
             1: timeInSec,
             2: timeInSec
        },
        sortList: [[1,1]]
    }); 
});
```

Resulting sorted table looks like this (sorted the following myself like you would see it in the browser):

```
...
<tr>
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td time="1411252">23 min 31 sec</td>
    <td time="352813">5 min 52 sec</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>225</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td time="1391952">23 min 11 sec</td>
    <td time="347988">5 min 47 sec</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>86</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Plum</td>
    <td time="1427192">23 min 47 sec</td>
    <td time="356798">5 min 56 sec</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>119</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Pear</td>
    <td time="1381072">23 min 1 sec</td>
    <td time="345268">5 min 45 sec</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>108</td>
</tr>
...
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the original tablesorter (v2.0.5b) from tablesorter.com, the above code will not work since the `textExtraction` function will not allow the targetting of specific columns.

However, you can use my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which does allow this option ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2373/))

The fork should work without any extra functions since it also has an alpha-numeric sort ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2375/)):

```
$(function () {
    $("#agentRapport").tablesorter({
        sortList: [
            [1, 1]
        ]
    });
});
```

But if you want to continue using the original version of tablesorter, you can use a parser, and save yourself from adding a `time="#"` attribute to every cell ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2374/)):

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "min&sec",
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table) {
        var min = (parseInt(s.match(/(\d+)(?:\s+min)/), 10) || 0) * 60,
            sec = (parseInt(s.match(/(\d+)(?:\s+sec)/), 10) || 0);
        return min + sec;
    },
    type: "numeric"
});

$(function () {

    $("#agentRapport").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            1: { sorter: "min&sec" },
            2: { sorter: "min&sec" }
        },
        sortList: [
            [1, 1]
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: did you see that I sort by a specific tag attribut? But it works when I change the js file. Exact version on the file would be helpful. Thanks @Mottie, good work!

Comment: Sorry, exact version on which file? If you mean my fork, the current version is 2.15.12. I did see that the code is extracting the value from the time attribute, but the parser will calculate the same number and save you the extra work of adding that time attribute to every cell.

Comment: Just thought about the [java-maven versioning convention ](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html). It's helpful to see what version your current library/js-file has.

Comment: Found it a nice idea instate of string parsing to use an attribut with a timestamp number. Thanks!